# Fetch API URL and put it in a specific column in the html table

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, fetch-api

I have 3 different API URLs in json form and I need to put them in a table that they correspond to. For example one of the urls is for names and it only contains the name, no other identifier. I need to put that into the table column that is only for names, since that is the only data on that one url. The other urls contain operate column data.I need to put the information from an api url into one empty.

This is what I have an it prints out to the console on the browser. I need to put this from the api url: ["Bob", "James"] into the names column of the table

```
fetch('URL').then((response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

This is my table:

```
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>VERSION1</th>
                <th>VERSION2</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```